# Virtual device manager quit unexpectedly, 2 mac displays

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have two mac displays, and whenever I try to start an avd, the avd manager quits unexpectedly.

(I found a solution to this question and am answering below)

Answer (score 3):

```
cd ~/.android/avd
cd your-avd.avd
```

add `window.x=0` to the `config.ini` file.

It's an ugly hack, but it worked for me right away.